# Связать кнопку формы и событие QFileDialog

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer, qfiledialog, getexistingdirectory

Изучаю *PyQt5*, в дизайнере создал форму, привязал к проекту. 
С событиями в виде клика на кнопку вроде-как разобрался. \

Пытаюсь привязать выбор папки на кнопку, не пойму почему:

> "Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)"

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QFileDialog

# Импортируем наш шаблон.
from mainform import Ui_MainWindow
import sys


class mywindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(mywindow, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        #
        self.ui.btn_select_dir.clicked.connect(self.btnSelectDIR)
        self.ui.btn_download_video.clicked.connect(self.btnSaveFile)

    def btnSelectDIR(self):
        #print(self.ui.link_save_to.text())

        dir_choose = QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self,
                                    "Выберите папку",
                                    self.cwd) # Начальный путь

        if dir_choose == "":
            print("\ nОтменить выбор")
            return

        print("\ nВы выбрали папку:")
        print(dir_choose)

    def btnSaveFile(self):
        print('save')


app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
application = mywindow()
application.show()

sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Ваш пример должен быть воспроизводимым. Вы не предоставили модуль **mainform.py**.
2. Чтобы получить реальную ошибку, всегда запускайте приложение в CMD/терминале/консоли.
3. Что такое `self.cwd` ?

---

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *

# ??? # Импортируем наш шаблон.
# ??? from mainform import Ui_MainWindow


#     v
class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__()
# ???        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
# ???        self.ui.setupUi(self)
# ???        self.ui.btn_select_dir.clicked.connect(self.btnSelectDIR)
# ???        self.ui.btn_download_video.clicked.connect(self.btnSaveFile)

        self.centralwidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.btn_select_dir = QPushButton("btn_select_dir")
        self.btn_select_dir.clicked.connect(self.btnSelectDIR)
        
        self.btn_download_video = QPushButton("btn_download_video")
        self.btn_download_video.clicked.connect(self.btnSaveFile)
        
        self.layout  = QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.btn_select_dir)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.btn_download_video)

    def btnSelectDIR(self):
        # ??? print(self.ui.link_save_to.text())

        dir_choose = QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(
            self,
            "Выберите папку",
# так:           
            QtCore.QDir.currentPath()                                         # Начальный путь
# или так:           
#            "."                                                              # ??? self.cwd  
        ) 

        if dir_choose:
            print(f"\nВы выбрали папку: {dir_choose}")        
        else:
            print("\nОтменить выбор")
#            return

    def btnSaveFile(self):
        print('def btnSaveFile(self):')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    application = MyWindow()
    application.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @andrey.medved577 что не так?